# Crypto Account hacked

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin-core-accounts

12 words password has been hacked and lost all the money in crpto account. Anyways to recover the money ? Please please help!

Comment: Bitcoin transaction aren't reversible and there is no centralised authority which can recover your funds after the hack. Please consider securing your seed phrase better next time.

Comment: Besides there's no point posting this here, I suppose you're using some service, why don't you ask directly their customer service? Even if we wanted to help we couldn't, as you don't provide any information about the wallet and/or service you're using. Here is some tip about seed phrase security you might find useful https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase

Answer (score 2):

If someone has gained knowledge of your wallet's mnemonic seed phrase, and used it to create a transaction which spends all of your funds to an address that the attacker controls, then there is no way to recover the funds once that transaction confirms (short of contacting the hacker, and asking nicely to have the funds returned).

Bitcoin transactions are fundamentally irreversible, I am sorry to say there is likely no way you will be able to recover the funds. Keeping your mnemonic seed phrase stored securely is of the utmost importance, for this very reason.